# Is nvm is relevant for node these days in windows, should I use it? and if yes why?

Tags: node.js

When I tried installing nvm from website - 
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows
everything went good, except the nvm use, even when I execute this command this doesn't seem to do its job properly though no error is thorwn by the terminal(cmd). When I try to use

```
node -v
```

it doesn't show the version number of node, that means node is not installed. And same goes witht the

```
npm -v
```

, this too doesn't show the version number, it hasn't been finding the executable. Everything works fine, that I install nvm install  too. nvm list says there it is, and it donwloads and saves it the its user/appdata/nvm folder,(I checked it). But still cmd can't find the executable. Do I manually need to set the path for the node folder that's located in the roaming/nvm/node folder.
[image: myPicture]

Comment: nvm helps you to manage multiple version of node on same machine. which is very essential if you are working on lot of projects and they require different versions.
so that way there should be a tool that helps, instead of installing new version every time.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/221#issuecomment-262363222

This comment solved the problem with one go, I guess the key was to use powershell, now node and npm works like smoothie. ;D